# why Operator precedence `and` higher then `or`

Tags: javascript

in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

if `and` higher then `or`,`1||alert(1)&&alert(2)` will alert but no

I think they are the same

Comment: Why do you think it will be 0? It should be 1 if `and` has higher precedence and it should also be 1 if `or` has higher precedence.

Comment: @slebetman if `||` had higher precedence it would be `2` actually

Comment: @zerkms: Ah, that's right

Comment: try is `1||(alert(1))&&alert(2)`

Comment: `1||(alert(1))&&alert(2)` returns `1` as expected and does not emit any alerts

Comment: @zerkms: Wait, if && have higher precedence, shouldn't both alerts be emitted?

Comment: @slebetman no, because the `1` (truthy) short circuits the evaluation, so the alerts are never even evaluated.

Comment: @adeneo Are you sure you've gotten the notion of "associativity" right here?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the expression:

```
1||0&&2
```

The expression is the same as the following:

```
1||(0&&2)//because && has greater precedence than ||
```

In which case 1 is the truthy value so you get 1.

So, with precedence rule this is not going to be like below:

```
(1||0)&&2//because || has lesser precedence than &&
```

Comment: I think you meant to write "greater" in both comments. As it is both the top and bottom comment says && has greater precedence (|| having lower precedence means the same thing as && having greater precedence)

Comment: No. It simply says && has greater precedence.

Comment: Well, in that case the comment in example 2 doesn't make sense because in that example the braces make || have greater precedence, not lesser. Or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to say?

Comment: I meant to say the expression 1||0&&2 will be as 1||(0&&2) not as (1||0)&&2 as per the precedence rule.

Comment: Yes. But what does the comment in the second example mean? Because it is saying "because && has greater precedence thatn ||" which is the same comment as above

Comment: I'm amazed you have got gold baze on javascript.

Comment: So you really mean to have both comment say the same thing? (second hint a > b means the same thing as b < a)

Comment: sorry I have no idea how to clear this things you up.

Comment: I just have one question: is the comment supposed to explain the code?

Comment: I am telling you last (in a hope you could understand) : `1||0&&2 cannot be same as (1||0)&&2//because || has lesser precedence than &&` but `1||0&&2 can be same as 1||(0&&2)//because && has greater precedence than ||`

Comment: I understand that, that was why I upvoted your answer because it is correct. But the comment is wrong. Since you refused to update the comment I had to remove my upvote.

Comment: I'm trying to explain to you that in the English language: the sentence `&& has greater precedence than ||` means the same as the sentence `|| has lesser precedence than &&` -- both comments say the same thing but the code are different so it doesn't make sense to me. The code examples are correct.

Answer (score 0):

> why Operator precedence `and` higher then `or`

Because that is how the language is defined. If it bothers you, then feel free to parenthesize to make the grouping clear.

Many other languages work this way.

A rule for remembering which has higher precedence is to think of `&&` as multiplication and `||` as addition (which they are, in a logical sense). Of course, multiplication has higher precedence (binds more tightly) than addition.

Comment: Its not just language but also in simple math we consider `and` to be greater precedence than `or`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple, multiplications come before additions and I hope you know that... The `and` is a logical product and the `or` is a logical addition.

So with logical operators you could rewrite your operation `(a||b&&c)` such as:

```
a + b * c
```

and if a, b, and c are Boolean and you apply the proper Boolean operation, it gives you the right result. You can translate that to one bit binary if you'd like:

```
&& => 1 * 1 is true, all others are false

|| => 0 + 0 is false, all others are true
```